# Java modified UTF-8 strings in Python

Tags: java, python, utf-8

I am interfacing with a Java application via Python. I need to be able to construct byte sequences which contain UTF-8 strings. Java uses a modified UTF-8 encoding in `DataInputStream.readUTF()` which is not supported by Python ([yet at least](http://bugs.python.org/issue2857))

Can anybody point me in the right direction to construct Java modified UTF-8 strings in Python?

Update #1: To see a little more about the Java modified UTF-8, check out the `readUTF()` method from the DataInput interface on line 550 [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/DataInput.java.html), or [here in the Java SE docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html).

Update #2: I am trying to interface with a third-party JBoss web app which is using this modified UTF-8 format to read in strings via POST requests by calling `DataInputStream.readUTF()` (sorry for any confusion regarding normal Java UTF-8 string operation).

Comment: What do you mean by "modified UTF-8"? As far as I'm aware Java uses an entirely standard UTF-8 if you ask it to encode to UTF-8. Note that Java's native string format is UTF-16 though.

Comment: Hi Jon, I added a link to the readUTF method in the DataInput interface which mentions it a little. I'll try to dig up some more info.

Comment: There is some info on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8 (so, serialization, some JNI and in-class string constants).

Comment: I would suggest modifying the Java application to use real UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks McDowell, I am trying to interface with a JBoss web app which is using this modified utf8 format to read in strings via POST requests.

Comment: Okay, that's a very specific serialization format - which is rather different to implying that Java breaks UTF-8 in general.

Comment: Thanks Tom but its a third part java app which I cannot modify so I must conform to its expected inputs.

Comment: Well the Modified UTF-8 adds solely a Null codepoint, which does more than you think: It embeds a new meaning inside a "string". What is this meaning? What do you do with Null bytes? (I suppose they are "field delimiters".) If you know that, it is easier to solve.

Answer (score 4):

You can ignore **Modified UTF-8 Encoding** (MUTF-8) and just treat it as UTF-8.  On the Python side, you can just handle it like this,

1. Convert the string into normal UTF-8 and stores bytes in a buffer.
2. Write the 2-byte buffer length (not the string length) as binary in big-endian.
3. Write the whole buffer.

I've done this in PHP and Java didn't complain about my encoding at all (at least in Java 5).

MUTF-8 is mainly used for JNI and other systems with null-terminated strings. The only difference from normal UTF-8 is how U+0000 is encoded. Normal UTF-8 use 1 byte encoding (0x00) and MUTF-8 uses 2 bytes (0xC0 0x80). First of all, you shouldn't have U+0000 (an invalid codepoint) in any Unicode text. Secondly, `DataInputStream.readUTF()` doesn't enforce the encoding so it happily accepts either one.

EDIT: The Python code should look like this,

```
def writeUTF(data, str):
    utf8 = str.encode('utf-8')
    length = len(utf8)
    data.append(struct.pack('!H', length))
    format = '!' + str(length) + 's'
    data.append(struct.pack(format, utf8))
```

Comment: U+0000 isn't the only difference. For code points that would be represented with surrogate pairs in UTF-16, modified UTF-8 encodes each component of the pair as if they were separate UTF-8 code points. This is pretty horrible because it means you have to convert from "modified UTF-8" to UTF-16, and then back in order to encode the correct code point.

Comment: I don't think you can ignore it: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 10: invalid start byte`

Answer (score 3):

*I know this question is very very old, but I still want to contribute, since I got in the same problem and solved it*

I found the implementation of this modified utf8 in the openjdk sources and translated it to python. here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/BarelyAliveMau5/000e7e453b6d4ebd0cb06f39bc2e7aec) to the gist i created.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if you need to read the format of `DataInput.readUTF`, I suspect you'll just have to convert the (well-documented) format into Python.

It doesn't look like it would be particularly hard to do. After reading the length and then the binary data itself, I suggest you use a first pass to work out how many Unicode characters will be in the output, then construct a string accordingly in a second pass. Without knowing Python I don't know the ins and outs of how to efficiently construct a string, but given the linked specification I can't imagine it would be very hard. You might want to look at the source for the existing UTF-8 decoder as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Python package that handles both reading and writing MUTF-8 strings with optional C extension: https://github.com/TkTech/mutf8

```py
from mutf8 import encode_modified_utf8, decode_modified_utf8

unicode = decode_modified_utf8(byte_like_object)
bytes = encode_modified_utf8(unicode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you, although it looks like it's the reverse of what you're doing:

[Connecting a Java applet to a python SocketServer](http://www.phaedro.com/javapythonutf8/)