# Unicode: Automatically detect high characters and convert them to surrogate pairs

Tags: java, python, unicode, utf-8

I want to write a program in python that writes a string to a file in a manner that a java application can read it. This java application reads the string in modified UTF-8 format (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921016/what-does-it-mean-to-say-java-modified-utf-8-encoding)). It basically means that all unicode characters have to be written as surrogate characters aka UTF-16BE. Is there a graceful, effective method that can do this.

I have tried the following to do so:

```
import re;
o_string = b''
for splitter in re.split("([\U00010000-\U0010FFFF])", w_string):
    if len(splitter) == 1 and ord(splitter) > 0xFFFF:
        o_string += splitter.encode("UTF-16")
    else:
        o_string += splitter.decode("UTF-8")
print(o_string)
```

But this seems so bulky (also it uses regex which seems to be en easy to dodge overhead). Can someone propose a better solution to this?

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393004/java-modified-utf-8-strings-in-python) help? (ie, this looks like a duplicate)